# url in a new window?

Tags: carto, url

I have a visualization in CartoDB, and I've added a Title Item with a url with the format [Name] (url). This url opens in the window of cartodb.

Is it possible to open the url in a new window?

Is it possible to add charts in cartoDB?

I have heard about Highcharts or Googlecharts, but I want to add the chart in the window of cartodb, I don´t have a own web page of html.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target="_blank"` to the url?
i.e. `<a href="http://www.''.com//" target="_blank">Click here</a>`

Comment: The format to add a url in a Title Item in CartoDB Visualization is: [Title](url). Not work to add target="_blank".